# gradle - build scala - Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, gradle, build.gradle

I am calling Scala object from my java code and trying to build a runnable jar using gradle. But I am not able to do that. Below is my Java code, Scala code, and `build.gradle` file.

**scala code:**

```
package hello

    class Hello_World {
      def main(args: Array[String])
      {
        println("Hello World");
      }
    }
```

**Java Code**

```
package hello;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hello_World hw = new Hello_World();  //Calling Scala Object
        hw.main(args);
    }

}
```

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "scala"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "java"

sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/scala"
sourceSets.test.scala.srcDir "src/test/scala"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = []



    repositories {

        flatDir {
        dirs "$projectDir/lib"
    }

}



dependencies{


    compile files("lib/scala-library-2.10.5.jar")
    compile files("lib/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar")
    compile files("lib/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar")


}



jar {

        manifest.attributes("Main-Class": 'hello.MainClass')
        baseName = 'hello'
        from configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
```

I am able to run a code in eclipse and export as jar from eclipse.  But When I build it using gradle, I am getting below error.

> PS C:\Users\pvijendr\Documents\hello> gradle clean build :clean
>   :compileJava UP-TO-DATE :compileScala FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
>
>   > xsbti/CompileFailed
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.397 secs

Can anyone help me or point out where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: you are calling scala main from java main.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yes. Is there any issue with that ?

Comment: I am not sure but if you change the function name is scala code, it should work. Just give it a try. :)

Comment: Actually code is working if I export from eclipse. I think there is no issues with the code.